# jQuery stop(); question

Tags: jquery

Im working on some hover effects on thumbnails. The function that im using are slideup and slidedown. Ive added the stop(true, true); to stop queuing of the animation. But it looks kinda bad when you move the mouse over the object fast. I would like a similar effect to the thumbnails on http://www.mio.se/ (hover). My current code is (with jquery easing plugin):

$(".dummy_product_x1").hover(

```
function () {

             $(this).children('.productdescription').stop(true, true).slideDown({
                 duration: 500,
                 easing: 'easeInCubic',
                 complete: function () { }
             });
         },
         function () {
             $(this).children('.productdescription').stop(true, true).slideUp({
                 duration: 500,
                 easing: 'easeOutCubic',
                 complete: function () { }
             });

         });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".productdescription").hover( function(e) {
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    // What you want
                });
```

You need to catch the event and then stopPropagation ;)